# What is the difference between the ideal $I=(x-1,x^2-y)$ and the ideal $J=((x-1)(x^2-y))$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

In the ring, $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, what is the difference between the ideal $I=(x-1,x^2-y)$ and the ideal $J=((x-1)(x^2-y))$?

This is probably a silly or obvious question but I am not yet familiar with multivariable polynomials. Can someone help me acknowledge the difference between $I$ and $J$. I am trying to find the common roots of the polynomials than belong to each of them.

Comment: $x-1\in I$ but $x-1\notin J$. That is, $J\subsetneq I$.

Comment: @Kenta S thank you. Can you help me define them? My first thought was that $I=\{f(x,y)(x-1)(x^2-y) \in I:  f(x,y) \in R \}$ but I am not so sure now...

Comment: $J=\{(x-1)(x^2-y)f(x):f(x)\in R\}$, whereas $I=\{(x-1)f(x)+(x^2-y)g(x):f(x),g(x)\in R\}$, where $R$ is the polynomial ring.

Comment: $I=\{(x-1)\cdot f(x,y)+(x^2-y)\cdot g(x,y)\mid f(x,y),g(x,y)\in R\}$ whereas $J=\{(x-1)(x^2-y)f(x,y)\mid f(x,y)\in R\}$.

Comment: Please make the body of your question self-contained - don't rely on the title to contain the whole question. I've edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal $I$ is the smallest ideal containing *both* the elements $a = x - 1$ and $b = x^2 - y$.
On the other hand, the ideal $J$ is the smallest ideal containing the product $ab$.
(The above is the difference in definition.)

---

More explicitly, we have $I = \{ar + bs : r, s \in \Bbb R[x, y]\}$ and $J = \{rab : r \in \Bbb R[x, y]\}$.
(To see why, argue that $I$ and $J$ are indeed ideals. Moreover, they must be contained in any ideal containing $\{a, b\}$ and $\{ab\}$, respectively.)

---

To see the difference as sets, note that $a \in I$ (by definition) but $a \notin J$. Indeed, suppose that $a \in J$. Then, $a = rab$ for some $r \in \Bbb R[x, y]$.
Analyse the degree of $y$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! Yes R is not the zero ring. I actually meant that R is the set of alll real numbers!